# Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined: angular

Tags: angularjs

I am building a vocabulary application that would sort the words based on the authors, books, tags, etc. the foll is an example of my JSON:

```
{
"expression": "mithrandir",
"meaning": "language of the elves",
"example": ["mithrandir is cool", "the elves speak mithrandir"],
"pronunciation": "",
"notes": "",
"meta": {
"book": ["There and back again"],
"author": ["Frodo Baggins"],
"tags": ["middle earth", "elves"]}
},
```

I have three drop downs in my view to filter agsinst book, author, and tags property in my json. Now the aforementioned lists are loading abs fine until i move my json to firebase.

the foll is my factory:

```
angular
    .module("ngClassifieds")
    .factory("classifiedsFactory", function($http, $firebaseArray){

        var ref = new Firebase('https://PATH.firebaseio.com/');

        return {
            ref: $firebaseArray(ref)
        }

    });
 })();
```

the foll is my controller:

```
angular

.module("ngClassifieds") 
.controller("classifiedsCtrl", function($scope, $state, $http, classifiedsFactory, $mdSidenav, $mdToast, $mdDialog) { 


    $scope.classifieds = classifiedsFactory.ref;
    $scope.classifieds.$loaded().then(function(classifieds) {
        $scope.tags = getTags(classifieds); // call the getTags method below
        $scope.books = getBooks(classifieds); // call the getBooks method below
        $scope.authors = getAuthors(classifieds); // call the getAuthors method below
        $scope.order = ""; //for sorting in asc or desc order
    });
```

'tags', 'books', and 'authors' are arrays that are used to capture the unqique properties. the foll is an example of the getTags() method.

```
function getTags(classifieds) {

        var tags = [];
        angular.forEach(classifieds, function(item) {
            angular.forEach(item.meta.tags, function(tag) {

                tags.push(tag);
            });

        });

        return _.uniq(tags);

    }
```

The foll is the error im getting in chrome:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined
at classifieds.ctr.js:135
at Object.forEach (angular.js:321)
at getTags (classifieds.ctr.js:134)
at classifieds.ctr.js:20
at processQueue (angular.js:15552)
at angular.js:15568
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16636)
at angular.js:16859
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5804)
```

And the foll is the error in firefox:

```
Error: item.meta is undefined
getTags/<@http://localhost:8080/components/classifieds/classifieds.ctr.js:135:5
forEach@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:321:11
getTags@http://localhost:8080/components/classifieds/classifieds.ctr.js:134:4
@http://localhost:8080/components/classifieds/classifieds.ctr.js:20:18
processQueue@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15552:28
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15568:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:16820:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:16636:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$evalAsync/<@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:16859:15
completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:5804:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost:8080/node_modules/angular/angular.js:6081:7
```

I realize that variations of this query have been floating around in the forum, but I've been unable to apply the solutions proposed in those threads to my code.

Comment: Can you share the exact value of the `classifieds` variable received inside the success callback?

Comment: You have something wrong with `classifieds`, please show value of that variable then I can figure out and help you.

Comment: Harpreet, im afraid im not sure what is it that you are referrin to here. i haev shared my controller code that is supposed to pooulate the lists once the data is loaded from firebase.

Comment: Thieu, Harpreet; im sharing the github repo. i hope that wld be helpful: https://github.com/sfumatostar/ngPalabras

Comment: The variable `classifieds` in `getTags(classifieds)` was never defined. Do you mean `getTags($scope.classifieds)`?

Comment: Please `console.log(classifieds)` and show me the result.

Comment: @str: nope, i mean getTags(classifieds) coz the 'classifieds' are now a passthru from the firebase once the classifieds are loaded. Before, when i was not using firebase, the foll is how it looked and everythin was loading all right: classifiedsFactory.getClassifieds().then(function(testwords) {

   $scope.classifieds = testwords.data; 
   $scope.tags = getTags($scope.classifieds);
   $scope.books = getBooks($scope.classifieds); 
     
   
  });

Comment: @Thieu when i console.log(classifieds): `'$scope.classifieds.$loaded().then(function(classifieds) {
   $scope.tags = getTags(console.log(classifieds));'` i get all the different objects from my firebase. for example: `Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:38"
$id
:
"-KCt8IL-X0xFc3Xz19Pz"
$priority
:
null
example
:
Array[2]
expression
:
"mithrandir"
meaning
:
"language of the elves"
meta
:
Object
notes
:
""
pronunciation
:
""`

Comment: I mean the result of `console.log(classifieds)`, not the code :)

Comment: @Nosail Please add `console.log(classifieds)` to inside of `function getTags(classifieds) {}` function, not like your example in above comment. Then give me your result in console of browser.

Comment: @Thieu Allright.is this how you mean? `function getTags(classifieds) {
   console.log (classifieds);
   var tags = [];
   angular.forEach(classifieds, function(item) {
    angular.forEach(item.meta.tags, function(tag) {

     tags.push(tag);
    });

   });
   
   return _.uniq(tags);`

Comment: @Nosail Yes, but I need to see the result of `console.log (classifieds)`, you can see it in Console of browser (Developer Tool)

Comment: @Thieu And in the console i get all the objets from firebase. and i also get the same error: `angular.js:13236 TypeError: Cannot read property 'tags' of undefined
    at classifieds.ctr.js:135
    at Object.forEach (angular.js:321)
    at getTags (classifieds.ctr.js:134)
    at classifieds.ctr.js:20
    at processQueue (angular.js:15552)
    at angular.js:15568
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16820)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16636)
    at angular.js:16859
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5804)`

Comment: @Nosail I just need only result of `console.log(classifieds)`, not all errors you got. Can you take a picture of your Console in Developer Tool?

Comment: Please alert(classifieds+'  ');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the result of `classifieds` variable (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnXIY.jpg), I think there's missing `meta` key in some specific objects.

Please update your `getTags` function like this and tell me your output:

```
function getTags(classifieds) {
    var tags = [];
    angular.forEach(classifieds, function(item) {
        if(item.meta){
          angular.forEach(item.meta.tags, function(tag) {
              tags.push(tag);
          });
        }

    });

    return _.uniq(tags);

}
```

Comment: This is the image. i hope this is what you were seeking. thanks [![console error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XwOj1.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XwOj1.png)

Comment: Thieu, THANKS VERY MUCH TIMES 10. you're right. not all my objects have information in the 'meta' property. this works now. im just curious as to the logic behind this operation. and thanks v much. i wouldn't have been able to pull this off without your assistance.

Comment: @Nosail You're welcome, I'm glad to help you. So, can you accept my answer?

Comment: Thieu; ive upvoted your answer; but it says that it will only reflect once i have 15 reputation points.

Comment: Ok, no prolem ^_^, happy coding, my friend!

Comment: Thanks Thieu. i really really appreciate your time and help on this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
      angular.forEach(item.tags, function(tag) {

            tags.push(tag);
        });
```

instead of

```
      angular.forEach(item.meta.tags,function(tag) {

            tags.push(tag);
        });
```

Comment: `tags` in inside of `meta`, I think your code is wrong.